# Is this valid in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

Is this valid in PHP?

```
foreach (function() { 
           return ['key' => 'Value'];
        } as $key => $val){
   $new_array = array('Key' => $key, 'Value' => $val);
}
```

I would like to add some logic in the `closure` to fetch dynmic array

Comment: why don't you just try it?

Comment: What PHP version are you usng?

Comment: I would like to use `if` statements inside the `closure` to return dynamic arrays

Comment: Im on `PHP 7.*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written this won't work because what you are trying to iterate over would be a `Closure` object created by anonymous function definition.

To have it work while organized like this you need to explicitly invoke your function right away, so what is iterated on is its return:

```php
foreach (
    ( function () {
        return [ 'key' => 'Value' ];
    } )() as $key => $val
) {
    $new_array = array( 'Key' => $key, 'Value' => $val );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Almost valid, 
this works, slightly modified the function, as to be able to see something:
https://3v4l.org/Tvja8

```
<?php
foreach ( (function() { return ['key' => 'Value'];})() as $key => $val){
   echo $key . ': '.$val;
}
```

Comment: Yes, requires PHP 7+

Comment: It works, help a child here, you added `(closure)()`, What do the brackets mean exactly?

Comment: More especially the second `()` ??

Comment: @Rarst explained it well, the second bracket does invoke the function, 
You could also pass parameters:
`(function($param) { return .... })($myParam)`

Answer (score 1):

It is valid if you encapsulate the function and call it. However it is not readable, so it would be better to define it outside the foreach loop:

```
foreach ((function() { 
              return ['key' => 'Value'];
         })() as $key => $val) {
   $new_array = array('Key' => $key, 'Value' => $val);
}
```

This would be more readable:

```
$function = function() { 
    return ['key' => 'Value'];
}

foreach ($function() as $key => $value) {
    $new_array = array('Key' => $key, 'Value' => $val);
}
```